# Several same product with a customizable field

Tags: commerce

I need a customizable field for a product in Drupal 8 drupal-commerce.
I succeeded to add such field through an order item type.
But if I want to add several same products on cart, this field stand uniq for all the products.

How can I have a line in cart by same product with the specific value of the customizable field for each one (I'd like to avoid the creation of a product variation by specific value. This specific value is customizable and so not in a finite set)  ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found how to answer to my need :-)

The configuration is done throught the product settings (Commerce>products then select the product to configure and click to edit)

In "Manage display" tab, edit the configuration of the "Variations" Field which is in Format "Add to cart form". Uncheck box "Combine order items containing the same product variation."

Hope it helps !!